# Does a user get question-banned from repeatedly downvoted questions?

Tags: discussion

In case of all of my questions are being downvoted (have minus score) am I likely to be banned from asking future questions?

Comment: The precise implementation of the ban process is not public. **We do not know the answer**.

Comment: Your [previous question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196405/banned-an-account) was closed as a duplicate. Did you read the duplicate? Then you should have gotten your answer. And keep in mind that even on Meta you can be post-banned at some point. Do your research please. Especially when we hand you the information.

Comment: Have you recieved the "We are not accepting questions from this account message? Or just getting lots of downvotes?

Comment: -1 because you seem to miss the points here. Keeping to ask for help over and over won't get you anywhere.

Comment: Last but not least.. all your questions so far on Meta are closed as duplicates - please do some research before asking.

Comment: As it comes up every time; deleted questions count too

Comment: @RichardTingle is correct and they count more than ordinary questions.

Comment: @david - stop editing your question in such a fashion; you're completely changing the context of your original question.  If you have a *new* question, *ask* a new question.

Comment: because this question is mark as duplicated, I want to edit so this question that is mark as duplicated is removed and possibly get upvoted.

Comment: Thats not the way it works, if its a new question it should be a "new question". Editing to become a completely different question completely invalidates Oden's answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The exact criteria for a question ban to take effect is not public knowledge, as it would allow people to circumvent it.

But, a large part of getting banned is asking many questions that get downvotes.

If you get a question ban, you will get a banner linking to [this document](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), which explains what the ban is and how to fix it.